# Remove codes from city names using regex

Tags: python, regex

I need to find a regex that is able to sanitize the input by removing city codes and keeping the name of the cities.

```
...
1105 AZ Amsterdam
AB25 2ZN Aberdeen
SY3 8XQ Shrewsbury
2XU Edinburh
NP20 2UB Newport
T4000 DGI San Miguel de Tucumán
BL9 7TD Lancashire
M13 9WL Manchester
L1H 7K4 Oshawa
...
```

Expected output:

```
...
Amsterdam
Aberdeen
Shrewsbury
Edinburgh
Newport
San Miguel de Tucumán
Lancashire
Manchester
Oshawa
...
```

I tried `r"([0-9-]+\b)|([A-Z]+[0-9-]+\b)"` but it takes only first codes

Comment: Are the codes always only at the start?

Comment: sometimes they appear at the end

Comment: How can you tell what is a code and what is a name? See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_short_place_names .

Comment: When you are asked for clarification it's best to edit your question rather than elaborating in comments. Questions should stand-alone, in part because not all readers read all comments (I missed that) and also because if the comment containing the question is deleted your answer will have no context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difficulty here is that you want to match a sequence of upper case letters, digits or spaces, but you don't want to match *only* a space, and probably you don't want to match anything that does not contain any digits.

Although there may be a simpler form, one thing that would work would be to insist on there being a digit, with any number of the other characters both before and after it.

The pattern should also start and finish on a word boundary, so that e.g. it does not strip off the capital letter at the start of the following word.

```
import re

re.sub(r'\b[A-Z\d ]*\d[A-Z\d ]*\b', '', address)
```

Output for the examples in the question:

```
Amsterdam
Aberdeen
Shrewsbury
Edinburh
Newport
San Miguel de Tucumán
Lancashire
Manchester
Oshawa
```

Output for `20007 Washington` mentioned elsewhere in a comment:

```
Washington
```

Inventing an example with the code at the end, namely:

```
Some other address SW1A 1AA
```

It gives:

```
Some other address
```

Note: if some of the codes do not contain any digits, then maybe what you could do is replace the `\d` in the middle with `(\d|[A-Z]{2})` so that it is also sufficient if it contains *two* upper case letters together. You would not want to treat a single upper case letter as a code, e.g. `A Coruña`.

Comment: What about `Tucumán`, as `á` is not ASCII?

Comment: @CarySwoveland That is not part of the string that has to be matched, so it doesn't matter. (See example output I've shown.) Only the letters in the codes themselves have to be ascii (you could not remove Á20 or something).

Comment: If you want to get the actual Tucumán written properly and using above regex then you can do this `print re.sub(r'\b[A-Z\d\s]*\d[A-Z\d\s]*\b', '', 'T4000 DGI San Miguel de Tucumán').decode('utf8')` but like @alani stated, that doesn't affect the regex and it's just processing that needs to happen after you run them through the regex.

Comment: @EdwardRomero Looks like you're using python 2? Anyway, assuming here that the input already has any non-ascii characters correctly encoded, and that it is simply a case of removing certain parts of the string.

Comment: @alani yes my assumption was that OP was using python 2 per the question about character. But yes python3 just prints it already decoded.

Comment: @EdwardRomero, good point. There is a choice of using `re.findall` (the city) or `re.sub` (the other bits). I was thinking in terms of the former.

Comment: @CarySwoveland You've expressed it better than I did, but yes, I was definitely thinking in terms of the codes that need to be removed, rather than whatever is left.

Comment: A couple of small suggestions: 1) change `\s` to a space (two places), so that newlines are not removed if the regex is applied to a multiline string (one line per city). 2. Add a `^` anchor so that "New L4500 York" does not become "New York". In general, if you want to match a space, I suggest you match a space character. Matching a whitespace can cause problems if you don't want to match line terminators.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I will change the `\s` to a space, thanks for the suggestion. Regarding the anchor, I will leave it because the OP said in a comment that the codes could be at the end of the string.

Answer (score 2):

The first step is to create a rule to specify what constitutes a valid city name, to be extracted, or what constitutes strings that are not part of the city name, to be converted to empty strings. I will do the latter, mainly because of the complexity introduced by having to match Unicode characters (e.g., "Tucumán").

It appears that the part at the beginning that is to be removed consists of one or more substrings, each comprised of two or more capital letters or digits, followed by one or more spaces. We can match that with the following regular expression.

```
r'^(?:[A-Z0-9]{2,} +)+'
```

[Start your engine!](https://regex101.com/r/xU1BH6/1/)

The SUBSTITUTION box at the link is empty.

Python's regex engine performs the following operations.

```
^                 : match beginnning of the string
(?:               : begin a non-capture group
  [A-Z0-9]{2,} +  : match 2+ uppercase letters or digits followed by 1+ spaces
)                 : end non-capture group
+                 : execute non-capture group 1+ times
```